# On button click launch youtube video in quicktime.

Tags: jquery, ios, html, youtube, touch

I'm working on a responsive website with a big video player.
For the video on desktop I just swap a picture with a youtube  when the user clicks on a custom play button.

My question is:
On touch devices there is any way to open the youtube video on the preset device player (quicktime in case of iOS) when the user clicks on a custom play button?

I want to avoid: click on custom play > click on youtube video > video lounched in quicktime

I want to have in stead: click on custom play > video lounched in quicktime

If you guys have an Idea on how to do it would be of great help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one button to open the video.. maybe it is better for the user..

for this you can do something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>  
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="mov_bbb.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

In HTML5 with the new video tag you can define the diferent type of the video, because every browser have another compatibility for this. look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) to see which browser suport which type of video.

you don´t have to care to launched the video, because the browser open the correct type for him.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

The only problem is that I have to use a youtube video, this because my client wants to count on youtube also the views from the site.

Would have ben much easier to use html5 video, but I can't...

Comment: why dont you use the iframe from youtube and embed directly for this situation?

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to do a better looking solution.

Comment: ok..you have to look how is the best for you... if you like my answer pls acept it